# Can you write Java code to check your local Internet Explorer's version

Tags: java, internet-explorer

Basically, I just need to write a simple java program to detect the version of my locally installed Internet Explorer.

There's javascript code, but it runs within your browser. what I want is some code like this:

```
public class VersionTest
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {    System.out.println("you IE Version is:" + getIEVersion());
   }

   public static String getIEVersion()
   {   //implementation that goes out and find the version of my locally installed IE
   }
}
```

How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check Internet Explorer's version in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916924/how-to-check-internet-explorers-version-in-java)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: I disagree.  This is actually a real question.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I agree, although the OP needs to learn to fix original questions rather than simply asking a slightly modified version again

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: Agreed.  I didn't realize it was the same poster.

Comment: Sorry guys. I thought once the question is closed, it cannot be modified and re-opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `Internet Explorer Registry Entry` for version. You can execute `Reg Query` from java using [Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) class. Reg Query is a command line tool to query registry entries in windows.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg query \"HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\" /v Version");
```

Complete code:

```
ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>()
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("reg query \"HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\" /v Version");
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()),8*1024);
BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()))
String s = null;
System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
output.add(s)

String internet_explorer_value = (output.get(2));
String version = internet_explorer_value.trim().split("   ")[2];
System.out.println(version);
```

Output = `9.0.8112.16421`

Output of `reg query` on my command prompt

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer
>
> Version    REG_SZ    9.0.8112.16421

Answer (score 2):

The registry entry you're looking for is at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Version
```

How do you read registry entries in Java? [Go read this Stack Overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java)

Answer (score 2):

```
private String getBrowserType(String currValue){
String browser = new String("");
String version = new String("");
if(currValue != null ){
if((currValue.indexOf("MSIE") == -1) && (currValue.indexOf("msie") == -1)){
browser = "NS";
int verPos = currValue.indexOf("/");
if(verPos != -1)
version = currValue.substring(verPos+1,verPos + 5);
}
else{
browser = "IE";
String tempStr = currValue.substring(currValue.indexOf("MSIE"),currValue.length());
version = tempStr.substring(4,tempStr.indexOf(";"));

}

}
System.out.println(" now browser type is " + browser +" " + version);

return browser + " " + version;

}
```

[Source](http://www.codemiles.com/servlets-jsp/how-can-we-get-browser-information-in-jsp-t1286.html)